# Port not released when I have a custom process.on('exit') in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

When I generally use Ctrl+c(mac) to stop a node process, the process is killed and port is released. When I am using process.on('SIGINT'), the process is not killed automatically, I have to manually kill the process in the port. Why is this behaviour?
Am I overwriting any default exit code snippet from executing?

```
process.on('SIGINT', (code) => {
    console.log(`About to exit with code: ${code}`);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Node's documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events):

> `'SIGTERM'` and `'SIGINT'` have default handlers on non-Windows platforms that reset the terminal mode before exiting with code `128 + signal number`. **If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).**

So yes, you are overwriting the default behaviour. If - when - you're done with handling the signal, you may call `process.exit()` to actually terminate the program - after possible listeners on `'exit'` have run.